# Can someone explain to me the mathematics behind the exponential function below?

Tags: c++, exponential

I saw the implementation of the exponential function shown below while I was reading about constexpr at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=vs-2019. I tried to understand the logic but couldn't.

I've tried Youtube and Google to search for an explanation but wasn't successful. So, could someone be kind enough to provide a source that I can read or explain it?

```
constexpr float exp(float x, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 :
        n % 2 == 0 ? exp(x * x, n / 2) :
        exp(x * x, (n - 1) / 2) * x;
};
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Historical note: this is also known as the Indian Exponentiation Algorith, and is about 2,000 years old. See here in MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107708/origin-of-square-and-multiply-algorithm

Comment: `x^(2n) = (x^2)^n` and `x^(m+1) = x*x^m`.

Comment: Anyway, making it iterative is easy for humans: `constexpr float pow(float x, unsigned n) noexcept { float r = 1; while (n) { if (n % 2) r *= x; x *= x; n /= 2; } return r; }` I'm not sure the compiler can do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources. They were really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process shown is sometimes called `fast exponentiation`.   Your code shows exponentiation by recursion.
Here’s the idea of exponentiation without `fast exponentiation`.  Let’s compute `x^32`. 
In pseudocode for nonnegative integer n :

```
long pow( x, n )
    if n == 0 
        return 1 //x^0 = 1
    else
        return x * pow( x, n-1)
```

The above code creates 33 calls to function pow: the initial call when n = 32 through the last call when n = 0.

Here’s a calculation of x^32  with `fast exponentiation`.

```
long pow( x, n )
    if n == 0
        return 1
    else if ( n % 2 == 0 ) // n is even 
        return  pow( x * x, n / 2)
        /* Note: x * x = x^2.  When n = 32, we return pow( x^2, 32/2)  or pow(x^2,16).  Also, note that (x^2)^16 = x^32*/
    else 
        return x * pow( x*x, (n - 1)/2 ) 
   /* Here, n is odd, so multiply by x and remove one from n. */
```

Return calls for fast exponentiation:

```
pow( x^2, 32), pow( x^2, 16 ), pow( x^2, 8 ), pow( x^2, 4 ), 
pow( x^2, 2 ), pow( x^2, 1 ), and x * pow( x^2, 0 )
```

This function made 7 calls to pow instead of 33 calls.  Hope this explanation clears things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now get the reasoning behind the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

This goes like this: we're trying to find `y` in `y = x ^ n`. Note, that `exp` is wrong name here - it should be `pow` (from power). Whole idea is based on this mathematical equation:

```
x ^ n = (x * x) ^ (n / 2) // assuming n is even
```

What do we do, when `n` is odd? We substract one from `n` and multiply result by `x`:

```
x ^ n = x * (x ^ (n - 1)) // assuming n is odd
```

since `n` is odd, `n - 1` is even and you use previous equation.

EDIT:
for this to work `n` must be non-negative, so `unsigned int` would be a better type for `n`.

Comment: Hmm. I understood why n must be non-negative. Thanks a lot!